# Am I missing something to get google maps to open from android webview

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, webview

Iam new to the android programming environment and am creating my first app. I am trying to get webview to open google maps when a google maps link is clicked within webview. Am I missing something as to why this is still opening the link in webview and not executing google maps instead? And when it is opening in webview it shows the destination fine but it does not show my location and states it is unable to determine my location on the bottom of the page being displayed

Here is the MainActivity

```
package com.example.micha.myapplication;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
 */
public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
 * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
 */
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                   GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
        // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    //webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.clearHistory();
    myWebView.clearFormData();
    myWebView.clearCache(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
            return false;
        }

        if(url.contains("https://www.google.com/maps/"))
        {
            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
            return true;
        }


        // Otherwise allow the OS to handle things like tel, mailto, etc.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity( intent );
        return true;
    }

});

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");



    //THIS IS TO DOWNLOAD THE PDF FILES OR OTHER DOWNLOAD LINKS
    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url)));
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }



  }



Here is the AndroidManifest.XML


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.micha.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_DIAL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"   />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_principal"
    android:label="Admin Tools"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

`if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {`

was preventing google maps from opening as it was forcing any url with https to stay within the webview. modified it to

`if( url.startsWith("http:")) {`

and all is good now.